# Setting some CNN/DNN weights to zero

Tags: neural-networks, supervised-learning

With *weight pruning* in CNN/DNN models, you can get rid of non-essential weights (set them to zero) after training. And then you can re-train the remaining weights, to improve any loss in accuracy. This is a common technique used in Model Compression [1,2].

From the above we can intuitively reason that certain weights/neurons are more susceptible to accuracy loss than others.

I would like to have more control over which weights in the CNN we can prune out, rather than making the decision after training, based on the trained weight value.

Assume I am going to freeze certain weights and training does not change them.

e.g., 
$W = [1,1,2,0,0,3]$
in the above we manually set $W_3, W_4$ to zero during initialization and the rest to random. During training $W_3, W_4$ will remain at zero.

**Question:**
How can I control the position of zero valued weights without much loss in accuracy ? Do you find anything clearly wrong with selective zero-initialization ?

thanks

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.00149

[2] https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/pruning_with_keras

Comment: Where do you get the certainty that "During training $W_3$,$W_4$ will remain at zero."?

Comment: I was thinking I can manually force it to be that way. Hoping other weights would get values that will compensate. Would this break the training process ?

Comment: Why would you want to have weights that are permanently zero?

Comment: I want to have more fine-grain control on which weights I can prune-off. Sort of like constraining the training process. do you think there will be serious challenges during training?

Comment: Right now, I don't understand why would you include these units into the model at all, if they are supposed to stay zero all the time and be pruned away in the end.

Comment: I have a similar thing to implement. To Jan Kukacka's question, for example, there are 2 filters in a conv layer where I would like to set different weights at 0 for different filters. Eventually, apply one filter or another based on the instance type, if that's architecturally possible. Let's say, that information that instances could be of different types, although, we don't know which one in the beginning, would be represented by having these two filters with different non-zero weights